# cron job not working in ubuntu server and output file is empty

Tags: server, 18.04, cron

I created a cron job in Ubuntu Server. It's supposed to upload a zip file to an FTP Server each 5 minutes

```
*/5 * * * * /home/osboxes/archive.sh > /home/osboxes/output.log
```

**archive.sh**

```
/usr/bin/python3 /path/to/the/command.py archive
```

I don't know why the cron does not work, because I have specified the path to Python. The output file is created but it's empty and does not contain any error.

The command works fine on terminal

```
cd /home/osboxes
./archive.sh
```

Comment: Did you test it in the terminal?

Comment: Yes when I run `archive.sh` from the terminal it works but not from cron

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen is this an issue with Ubuntu Server ? Because I had tested it in Ubuntu Desktop and the cron worked fine

Comment: Well it depends on what your script is doing, this might not be possible in the server!

Comment: If you want to redirect *errors* to the log, you will need to add `2>&1` to the end of the command - as it stands, it's only redirecting the standard output stream

Comment: Now it shows `No module named pdfminer3`. Does it mean that cron doesn't have access to python packages ?

Comment: No, it means that `cron`'s `$PATH` is different. See `man 5 crontab`.